# Pandas Shift columns but add new rows where non-shifted columns are null

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

```
  x y
0 1 5
1 2 4
2 3 3
3 4 2
4 5 1
```

I want to run something like `df.y.shift(3)` and it will not only shift `y` down 3 rows but also create three new rows for `x` that are null so that the dataframe becomes

```
  x y
0 1 N
1 2 N
2 3 N
3 4 5
4 5 4
5 N 3
6 N 2
7 N 1
```

Where `N=NaN`

The shift operator only seems to shift a column down n rows but will also "knock" n items from your list. I want to keep those n item on my new dataframe.

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: The second list is expected output. It looks like Yakym Pirozhenko has answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex first, and then shift only one of the columns:

```
df = df.reindex(range(8))
df["y"] = df.y.shift(3)

     x    y
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN
3  4.0  5.0
4  5.0  4.0
5  NaN  3.0
6  NaN  2.0
7  NaN  1.0
```